# How to retrieve value from array of array of object angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I have JSON like this, which is stored in variable.

```
data=[  
   [  
      {  
         "fdate":"01-01-2018",
         "pdate":"31-12-2018",
         "range":"01-01-2018 - 31-12-2018",
         "nlist":[  ],
         "nplist":[  ]
      }
   ],
   [  
      {  
         "fdate":"01-01-2018",
         "pdate":"31-12-2018",
         "range":"01-01-2018 - 31-12-2018",
         "nlist":[  ],
         "nplist":[  ]
      },
      {  
         "efdate":"21-01-2018",
         "expdate":"31-12-2018",
         "range":"21-01-2018 - 31-12-2018",
         "nlist":[  ],
         "nplist":[  ]
      }
   ]
]
```

How to get the range from here in typescript file, please advice.

I am trying to retrieve like this, but its not working

```
for(let i=0; i< this.data.length; i++){
            this.other +=  this.data[i].range;
            }
Console.log(this.other);
```

Please advice or let me know if any better way to do this

Comment: Your data is a bit wild, but to get the first range you can use `data[0][0].range`

Comment: Where do you need this value? Can you add some code?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Kindly post expected output

Comment: I have updated the question, added the ts code as well, please guide or any better way to do this.

Comment: Even console.log is spelled wrong. I'm pretty sure this is an async problem; post the code you are using, otherwise nobody can help you

Comment: @bambam console.log spelling was typo, but i am using same code in ts file, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
for(let i=0; i < this.data.length;i++){
    for(let j=0; j < this.data[i].length;j++){
        this.other +=  this.data[i][j].range;
        console.log(this.data[i][j].range); // What you want to do here...
    }   
}
```

Here is working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8j5hkk

Hope this help you!!!!

Comment: Thank you for the response, but its showing undefined, could you please show me the working example, any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data=[  
   [  
      {  
         "fdate":"01-01-2018",
         "pdate":"31-12-2018",
         "range":"01-01-2018 - 31-12-2018",
         "nlist":[  ],
         "nplist":[  ]
      }
   ],
   [  
      {  
         "fdate":"01-01-2018",
         "pdate":"31-12-2018",
         "range":"01-01-2018 - 31-12-2018",
         "nlist":[  ],
         "nplist":[  ]
      },
      {  
         "efdate":"21-01-2018",
         "expdate":"31-12-2018",
         "range":"21-01-2018 - 31-12-2018",
         "nlist":[  ],
         "nplist":[  ]
      }
   ]
]

var calc = calculateRange(data);
console.log(calc)
function calculateRange(_data){
   var r = "";
   for(var i=0;i<_data.length;i++){
       var isArray = Array.isArray(_data[i]);
       if(isArray){
        r+=calculateRange(_data[i]);
       }else{
        var x = _data[i].range;
        r+= typeof x != "undefined"? x:"";
       }
   }
   return r;
}
```

You can use a logical loop, the sample is above.

Comment: Thank you foe the response, its running in infinite loop and showing false.. false..in console, please advice.

Comment: Can you give the trace of _data[i]

Comment: its showing (99586)false in app.component.ts:  line number 357

Comment: It's a wild guess may be its occuring because every element is coming as STRING or object. Can you try the same with var rData = JSON.parse(data); and var calc = calculateRange(rData);

Comment: Thank you for the response, its working fine now, could you please guide me, how to display calc in another drop down,

Answer (score 0):

```js
this.data=[
  [
     {
        "fdate":"01-01-2018",
        "pdate":"31-12-2018",
        "range":"01-01-2018 - 31-12-2018",
        "nlist":[  ],
        "nplist":[  ]
     }
  ],
  [
     {
        "fdate":"01-01-2018",
        "pdate":"31-12-2018",
        "range":"01-01-2018 - 31-12-2018",
        "nlist":[  ],
        "nplist":[  ]
     },
     {
        "efdate":"21-01-2018",
        "expdate":"31-12-2018",
        "range":"21-01-2018 - 31-12-2018",
        "nlist":[  ],
        "nplist":[  ]
     }
  ]
]
for(let i=0; i< this.data.length; i++){
for(let t = 0; t < this.data[i].length; t++) {
     console.log(this.data[i][t].range);
      }
    }
```

In html page you can retrieve like this

```
 <div *ngFor="let i of data">
    <p *ngFor="let t of i">{{t.range}}</p>
</div>
```

or in your ts you can do like this

```
 for(let i=0; i< this.data.length; i++){
     for(let t = 0; t < this.data[i].length; t++) {
          console.log(this.data[i][t].range);
           }}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, html its showing, but in typescript its showing undefined, I need to do some more stuffs in ts file, please advice